Powershell Add alert action with Set-AzResource
I am attempting to add an alert action for all alert types in a resource group using powershell.
I am able to get the properties of the alerts using :
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -ExpandProperties
write-output($resource.Properties.actions | Format-List *)

This returns the following :
actionGroupId     : /subscriptions/345345/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/m
                    icrosoft.insights/actionGroups/Teams-Alerts
webHookProperties : @{teamsChannel=MyChannel}

I would like to update both of these values, or add them if they do not exist. So starting with the actionGroupId, I tried :
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceType microsoft.insights/metricAlerts -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup"
$Resource.Properties.actions.actionGroupId  = "/subscriptions/456546/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/Teams-Alerts"
$Resource | Set-AzResource -Force

But that returns with an error :
The property 'actionGroupId' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

SO how do I update or add an actiongroup to an alert?
Thanks!


Powershell Add alert action with Set-AzResource

Here is the PowerShell script to add the alert action for existing alert.
$alertRule = Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Name "Teams-alert"  
  
$actionGroup = Get-AzActionGroup -Name "venkat-actiongroup" -ResourceGroupName "venkat"  
  
$targetResourceId = "/subscriptions/sub-ID/resourceGroups/Venkat/providers/microsoft.insights/components/venkat-insighta"  
  
$activityLogActionGroup = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup"  
$activityLogActionGroup.ActionGroupId = $actionGroup.Id  
  
$condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "availabilityResults/availabilityPercentage" -TimeAggregation Aveage -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 0.1  
  
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 `  
-Name "Teams-alert" `  
-ResourceGroupName "Venkat" `  
-WindowSize "00:05:00" `  
-Frequency "00:05:00" `  
-TargetResourceId $targetResourceId `  
-Condition $condition `  
-ActionGroup @($activityLogActionGroup) `  
-Severity 3  

Output:

Reference: Add-AzMetricAlertRule

I have alerts that are not metric alerts, which is why I am using Get-AzResource instead of Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2
